# How do I run Android SDK as root in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, android

When I run `gksudo android` I receive a password prompt but after entering the password nothing opens. I have then tried running terminal as root then running `android` command but then the command is not recognized. I have tried looking for other shortcuts but I cannot think of any now. The reason I need to run as root is because my android sdk is locate in `usr/local` folder. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the directory `/usr/local/android-sdk/tools` (I assume this is where you installed the SDK) is not in the PATH variable of root. So your system has no idea where the SDK manager is located.

To change this permanently and most easily, open  `/etc/bash.bashrc` in an edior with elevated privileges and add the following line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/android-sdk/tools:/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools
```

This will add the Android SDK path to all users, not just root. If you only want to set it for root, edit `/root/.bashrc`.

Additionally, this command adds the `platform-tools` directory, where tools like ADB and fastboot reside.

Comment: "Path file"? what do you mean with that? And yes, if you want to add something to the PATH variable, you can do so globally in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or for a single user in `.bashrc` in his home.